# Solving two systems of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the following system of linear equations:$$A x = 0 \\
B x = y\\ Cx=c$$ Suppose that $[A; B]$ ($B$ stacked below $A$) is square and invertible, so that $x$ is determined given $y$. However, instead of $y$, we are given $c$, which indirectly pins down $y$ through the third equation ($y$ and $c$ have the same length, and $C$ has full row rank.)

To summarize, we are given $A$, $B$, $C$ and $c$. I am interested in solving the system numerically for $x$ and $y$.

What would be a good approach to doing so that scales well in the case where $A$ and $B$ are large and sparse. For instance, is there any way to reduce the problem into an auxiliary problem where I can use standard tools for solving systems of linear equations (which are well-developed for large, sparse systems)?

Comment: You dont need to solve $A$ at all. Just solve the second equation for $x$ (solution is of course not unique when $B$ is not square, you have to choose a solution), and then multply $Ax$ to get $y$. Maybe im missing what the question is?

Comment: @Simon Ah yes, when simplifying my problem to ask the question, I ended up simplifying too much. $y$ is restricted to be non-zero elements in only the first $n$ elements, where $n$ matches the length of $c$.

Comment: In that case, you should split the first equation in an upper part $A_1 x = y_1$ and a lower part $A_2 x = 0$. Then write the second part together with the $Bx=c$ equation to get a single square problem. For that you can use any standard method: explicit matrix decompositions (LU, QR and friends) if the problem is small; and iterative methods (CG, MINRES, GMRES, BiCGSTAB, ...) if the problem is big

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks! (I edited the question to reflect the refinement on $y$)